# Makefile always thinks project is up to date - but files don't even exist

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CCC = g++
CCFLAGS = -ansi

driver: driver.o graph.o
        $(CCC) -o driver driver.o graph.o

graph.o: graph.h
driver.o: graph.h

adjl:
        rm -f graph.h graph.cc
        ln -s adjl/graph.cc .
        ln -s adjl/graph.h .
        touch graph.cc graph.h
adjm:
        rm -f graph.h graph.cc
        ln -s adjm/graph.cc .
        ln -s adjm/graph.h .
        touch graph.cc graph.h

clean:
        rm -f *.o
real_clean: clean
        rm -f graph.cc graph.h
        rm -f driver
```

The idea is that I am trying to link two different .cc/.h files depending on which implementation I want to use.  If I make real_clean, none of the .cc/.h files exist, I merely have a driver.cc file and the makefile in the folder.  If I call make, it says they are up to date.  This happens even if I edit the files in adjl/adjm to make them "newer" versions.

```
 [95]% ls
adjl/  adjm/  driver.cc  makefile
 [96]% make adjl
make: `adjl' is up to date.
 [97]% make adjm
make: `adjm' is up to date.
```

I took the template makefile from another project I had done, and they are written the same way but I can repeatedly make the same commands with no "up to date" issues.

I have googled but have not found a problem similar to mine (they generally seem to involve users who aren't cleaning before making).

Thanks to anyone for reading.

Comment: It does, make and real_clean both work.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it does work.  I just copied a makefile from a previous class and it works, my understanding of how they work however is very slim.

Comment: make has implicit rules (e.g. that invoke a c++ compiler to make a .o from a .cc) so that's why there're no other lines for driver.o, for e.g. However, the dependency on the `.h` must be explicitly stated (because make doesn't deduce it from the source file).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**The problem is that you have directory named the same as your targets in Makefile.**

When you issue `make adjl` make checks for file `adjl` which it finds and does nothing.
Rename targets to something else and try again.

Answer (score 13):

The `adjl` and `adjm` targets are real targets. Since they have no dependencies, and the files are present (the 2 directories in your listing), make doesn't do anything (because they are around).

However, what you want is to specify `adjl` and `adjm` as phony targets (so that the commands are executed when you specify them). To do so,

```
.PHONY: adjl adjm
```

Read http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Phony-Targets.html for more information.

**EDIT**

In fact, the `real_clean` and `clean` rules should probably also be made phony.

Comment: That fixed my problem, thank you.  I am still confused as to why my old makefile (which did not have a .PHONY line) worked.  To my eye they look structurally identical.  I will read the link, thanks for the help.

Comment: if the file does not exist then the rule (if invoked directly/indirectly) will be executed (because it doesn't exist). if nothing creates the file, then everytime the rule is invoked, it will execute (because it still doesn't exist). that's probably why it worked. it's also why "real_clean" works in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Your have directories with the same name as your targets.

Since your targets don't depend on anything, they'll always be considered up to date.

When specifying a target that isn't linked to a file on disk, you need to use the special target `.PHONY`:

```
.PHONY: adjl adjm
```

You should also do the same for your clean and real_clean targets as well - otherwise they'll break if someone creates a file called "clean".